# What does this error mean "setDataSource: outside path in JNI is ?x@"

Tags: java, android

Hi I am keep getting this `E/MediaPlayer-JNI(14285): setDataSource: outside path in JNI is ?x@` in my logcat. What this means?

Answer (score 0):

Mine problem was solved after setting MediaControllers setAnchorView and setMediaPlayer with the videoView.

```
                MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
                mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
                mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

                videoView.setMediaController(mc);
                videoView.setVideoURI(myUri);
                videoView.start();
```

I am still getting the message in error logcat. If anyone knows what the problem is please share.